# why when trying to create a jar file my cmd says it cannot recognize the command?

Tags: java, jar, cmd, exe, drjava

I am unable to to get my already complied and saved `.java` file will not be complied in the cmd and it will not allow me to create a `.jar` file because the terminal is telling me`'jar' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` it gives me the same output when i try the `javac` command to compile.

I need to create the `.jar` in order to continue in creating an `.exe` correct? or is there another way?

Im also working in drJava which might be an issue but i dont know?

Comment: Post the actual statement you are typing in cmd

Comment: Are you sure the `jar` program is in the environment path variable, or that it's truly installed?

Comment: @kevin628 i dont know what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<JDK_HOME>\bin` directory should be in your PATH environment variable:

```
set PATH=c:\java\jdk_xx\bin;%PATH%
```

And you won't be able to create a .exe file. Java programs are launched using the `java` command.

This should be covered by the first chapter of your Java book or tutorial. Read it.

Comment: I have read it and i did what you said however it still is not working

Comment: Edit your question and explain where your JDK is installed, the exact sequence of commands you executed, and the exact output it gave.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Does the jar command require a separate path variable, because I am able to use the java and javac commands without issue, but I get the error message posted above when I try to create a jar file using the jar command.